# killing all the processes related to a script

Tags: shell-script, terminal

I have a script that calls a lot of programs sequentially. How could I terminate this script once and for all? I know that I could click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel some of the process but killing the whole process would require clicking that multiple (even thousands or tens of thousands) times. How could I terminate one script by simply one clock or one command? (or multiple command?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Ctrl + C` signal never reaches the script, but only the launched processes. You can try to leave your finger on the `C` when pressing `Ctrl + C` continuously. Eventually, the signal reaches the shell and no new programs are being started.

Or, you can hit `Ctrl + Z`, then type `kill %1`.

This suspends the entire script, and then kills off everything.

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. Get the script name (say abc.sh)
 2. ps -ef | grep "abc.sh" | awk '{print "kill "$2}' > file.sh
 3. /bin/bash file.sh
```

You can use option -9 with kill. This will also kill the parent process if abc.sh script has some parent process. So would suggest use it wisely. Most of the cases it would work fine with above 3 steps.